# How to add XElements dynamically in a loop?

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, linq-to-xml, xelement

I get an HybridDictionary with all the child XElements.
I don't know ahead how many items I have there.
So instead of doing this:

```
xmlDoc.Element("Parent").Add(
     new XElement("Child", new XAttribute("Name", "Child1"),
           new XElement("Id", "796"),
           new XElement("Name", "gdsa")
           etc..
      ));
```

I'm trying to do something like that:

```
Strung [] allKeys = new String[ChildElements.Count];
TheHybridDictionary.Keys.CopyTo(allKeys, 0);

xmlDoc.Element("Parent").Add(
      new XElement("Child", new XAttribute("Name", "Child1"),
            for (int i = 0; i < TheHybridDictionary.Count; i++)
                   new XElement(allKeys[i], TheHybridDictionary[allKeys[i]])
```

But how to connect whatever is inside the for loop to be part of the XML document construction?

Comment: Just add them one by one?

Comment: Yes, exactly.. from an HybridDictionary. The for loop itself is correct, but I don't know how to connect it to the whole structure.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < TheHybridDictionary.Count; i++)
                  xmlDoc.Element("Parent").Add( new XElement(allKeys[i], TheHybridDictionary[allKeys[i]])`

Comment: They should be under the "Child" element, not the "Parent". The loop replaces the Id and Name in the first example

Comment: Oh, i misread your brackets :). You can still use that for the children as well, though Linq is nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, your `HybridDictionary` class does not implement `IEnumerable`, so you can't use LINQ on it directly.

But you can use `allKeys` string array instead:

```
string [] allKeys = new String[ChildElements.Count];
TheHybridDictionary.Keys.CopyTo(allKeys, 0);

xmlDoc.Element("Parent").Add(
    new XElement("Child", new XAttribute("Name", "Child1"),
        allKeys.Select(x => new XElement(x, TheHybridDictionary[x])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .Add() method as in Stefan's comment, or use LINQ:

```
xmlDoc.Element("Parent").Add(
  new XElement("Child", new XAttribute("Name", "Child1"),
        TheHybridDictionary.Select(kvp => new XElement(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)));
```

Comment: Make sure you have "using System.Linq" at the top.

Comment: I have "using System.Linq"

Comment: Looks like `HybridDictionary` does not implements `IEnumerable`, like standard `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does.